# How to escape single quote,double quotes and backlash in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I make a query and i have query result. I put the query result in javascript function but there is an error because single quote,double quotes, slashes , + and etc.. include in there result. How to solve this?

```
function add(1,'10 Units (Manastone: Crit Strike +19 / Attack +2)',3);
```

Above is the function I would like to use. But "10 Units (Manastone: Crit Strike +19 / Attack +2)" make my code stop.

Comment: can you tell us what error actually you are getting

Comment: Is it a new function or a call? Because we usually call functions without the word "function" and declare them like this 'function asd(){/*...*/}'. I'm not a big js guru but this is common.

Comment: it is a call from html like these <button onclick="Blur.add(1,'10 Units (Manastone: Crit Strike +19 / Attack +2)',3)"

Comment: add is a Blur class method? Blur is instanciated ? Give your console error messages , but i think your method was detectd in private ( use this.add = function() { } to declare public method ).

Answer (score 1):

To call javascript function , you must do :

```
add(1,'10 Units (Manastone: Crit Strike +19 / Attack +2)',3);
```

instead of

```
function add(1,'10 Units (Manastone: Crit Strike +19 / Attack +2)',3);
```

Your mistake is simple. You're mix function declaration

```
function maFunc( param1, ... ) {}
```

and function calling :

```
maFunc( "myParamValue1", ... ) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your call function by saying:

```
add(// parameters);
```

You declare function like:

```
function add(// parameters);
```

Comment: Please, read other answer before to post yours. This point was already check in answers and in comment...